# How can I do 2-level menu like the one found here ... (ASP.NET MVC3 + Razor + MvcSiteMap)

Tags: asp.net, razor, mvcsitemapprovider

How can I do 2-level menu like the one found here http://www.tv.com/ncis-los-angeles/show/76607/summary.html with MvcSiteMap ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)

Comment: Is it not possible to do the 2-level menu with MvcSiteMap ? Instead of using Javascript ?